# Is there a way to pass keys as a variable in a DataFrame's 'get' method in pandas?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

So I have an Excel dataset with 2 sheets that I want to read using pandas. To make the code more dynamic, I decided to store the sheet names list into a variable which I later pass into the 'get' method to create separate DataFrames for both.

```
import pandas as pd

# access all sheets as one DataFrame
excel_file = pd.ExcelFile(r"C:\Users\user\Desktop\example.xlsx")
email_list = pd.read_excel(excel_file)
sheets = excel_file.sheet_names

# separate sheets into separate DataFrames.
sheet1 = email_list.get(sheets[0])
sheet2 = email_list.get(sheets[1])
```

Then from these DataFrames I exract a column of emails as a Series

```
sheet1list = sheet1['Email']
sheet2list = sheet2['Email']
```

But when I run it, I run into the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\ga201\Desktop\My Python Projects\main.py", line 30, in <module>
    sheet1list = sheet1['Email']
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

1. Why does it make the `sheet1` variable a NoneType?
2. Is there a way to actually use it through variables or is the only
   way to type in the sheet name?

Just curious. I've tried using f strings, but they don't work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're misinterpreting the default behaviour of [pd.read_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html). If you don't specify the parameter `sheet_name`, the function will only return the *first* sheet as a DataFrame.

Use `email_list = pd.read_excel(excel_file, sheet_name=None)` to get DataFrames for all sheets.

The return value will now be a dictionary of DataFrames with the sheet_names as keys.

Comment: Right...I keep forgetting that. Works like a charm now, thanks!